# Is the default value for the padding is always 0 for all elements?

Tags: html, css, padding

Is the default value for the padding is always 0 for all elements? Are there any exceptions and if so, then when?

Comment: I think list <li>elements have padding by default

Comment: As button, input, and probably some other elements

Comment: I would suggest using a reset values like so: https://elad2412.github.io/the-new-css-reset/

Comment: I was also setting some initial resets and some people do not include padding: 0; and only reset the margin but some do include the padding. I just wanted to find out if padding default is really 0 or not.

Comment: The HTML5 spec lists nine elements (including some that are obsolete) that are expected to have default non-zero padding. That doesn't include form controls whose precise internal rendering is not currently specified there.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CSS 2.2 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#padding-properties):

> Name: padding-top, padding-right, padding-bottom, padding-left
> Initial:  0
> Applies to:   all elements except table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group and table-column

Comment: I was also setting some initial resets and some people do not include padding: 0; and only reset the margin but some do include the padding. I just wanted to find out if padding default is really 0 or not. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Gladly :) if it's correct, please mark it with the check mark and maybe an upvote